# onChildRemoved() method calls multiple time even there is only one child in my firebase data

Tags: android, firebase

i have only one child in firebase url and i periodically update the value of it. however i don't know why onChildAdded() called when i change the value of child.

onChildRemoved() is also called multiple time when i removed child from firebase url even if the child is only one.
firebase data
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP6Sj.png

**NOTE**

i periodically change the values of node by using service

childeventlistener = new ChildEventListener() {

```
                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot arg0) {

                        Log.e("child_removed", "");
```

//this log printed multiple times when i delete the node from firebase.
                        }

```
                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot arg0, String arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot arg0,
                            String arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try {
                            String firebase_get_value = arg0.getValue()
                                    .toString();

                            Log.e("firebase get value", firebase_get_value
                                    + "");

                            locationDetails = new Gson().fromJson(
                                    firebase_get_value,
                                    new TypeToken<BeanFireBase>() {
                                    }.getType());

                            lat_from_firebase = locationDetails
                                    .getLatitude();
                            lon_from_firebase = locationDetails
                                    .getLongitude();
                            timestamp_from_firebase = locationDetails
                                    .getTimestamp();

                            accuracy_from_firebase = locationDetails
                                    .getAccuracy();

                            latitude_from_fb = Double.valueOf(
                                    lat_from_firebase).doubleValue();
                            longitude_from_fb = Double.valueOf(
                                    lon_from_firebase).doubleValue();

                        } catch (Exception exception) {

                            Log.e("Exception--->",
                                    "" + exception.getMessage());

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot arg0,
                            String previousChildName) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "onChildAddedCalled" + previousChildName,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                        try {
                            String firebase_get_value = arg0.getValue()
                                    .toString();

                            locationDetails = new Gson().fromJson(
                                    firebase_get_value,
                                    new TypeToken<BeanFireBase>() {
                                    }.getType());

                            lat_from_firebase = locationDetails
                                    .getLatitude();
                            lon_from_firebase = locationDetails
                                    .getLongitude();
                            timestamp_from_firebase = locationDetails
                                    .getTimestamp();

                            accuracy_from_firebase = locationDetails
                                    .getAccuracy();

                            latitude_from_fb = Double.valueOf(
                                    lat_from_firebase).doubleValue();
                            longitude_from_fb = Double.valueOf(
                                    lon_from_firebase).doubleValue();

                        } catch (Exception exception) {

                            Log.e("Exception--->",
                                    "" + exception.getMessage());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                };

                myFirebaseRef.child("" + code_to_track)
                        .addChildEventListener(
                                childeventlistener);

//i have used below code to set and update data on firebase
Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            updates.put("lat", "" + latitude_to_send);
            updates.put("lon", "" + longitude_to_send);
            updates.put("timestamp", "" + time_millis_to_send);
            updates.put("accuracy", "" + accuracy_to_send);
            myFirebaseRef.child("" + set_child).child("LocationInfo").updateChildren(updates);

// and this is how i delete node from firebase
myFirebaseRef.child("" + set_child).removeValue();
```

Comment: Can you show how your firebase database look like? Also show on which URL you have set your `ChildEventListener`.

Comment: firebase data: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qP6Sj.png

And using below firebase object value to set and fetch the data
myFirebaseRef = new Firebase(
    "https://blinding-fire-482.firebaseio.com/Users");

Comment: Can you tell me how are you updating the value of the child node?

Comment: And also how are you deleting a child?

Comment: Map<String, String> updates = new HashMap<String, String>();
    updates.put("lat", "" + latitude_to_send);
    updates.put("lon", "" + longitude_to_send);
    updates.put("timestamp", "" + time_millis_to_send);
    updates.put("accuracy", "" + accuracy_to_send);
    myFirebaseRef.child("" + set_child).child("LocationInfo")
      .setValue(updates);
//where set_child variable is random no.

Comment: myFirebaseRef.child("" + set_child).removeValue();
//set_child is particular random no. on firebase

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the value of your child but you are actually creating a new child with a name `set_child` and adding it to your `users` node. Rather than generating a random name for you child node you should use `push()` to insert a new node as `push()` will automatically generate a unique name for your child node.

`setValue()` saves data to the specified `Firebase` reference, replacing any existing data at that path ,which means that it removes the current path and reinserts it with the new values specified by you.
Whereas `updateChildren()` will keep the path intact and just replace the end values.

**NOTE**

Here `set_child` should be a already existing child otherwise it would add a new child to your `users` and therefore `onChildAdded()` will get called.

This is how you can update the value of a already existing child of the `users` node.

```
Map<String, String> updates = new HashMap<String, String>();
updates.put("lat", "" + latitude_to_send);
updates.put("lon", "" + longitude_to_send); 
updates.put("timestamp", "" + time_millis_to_send); 
updates.put("accuracy", "" + accuracy_to_send); 
myFirebaseRef.child("" + set_child).child("LocationInfo") .updateChildren(updates);
```

Comment: so will it override the old one ??

Comment: By override do you mean that it will replace a already existing child of `users`?

Comment: will it create another hidden child with the same name??

Comment: If your say `push()` on your `users` node it will create a unique random name for its child node.

Comment: yup but i dont want to create new node...rather i want to update the value only

Comment: Ok i'll edit my answer to write the code to update existing value.

Comment: sorry sir...but the problem still exists... :(

Comment: Ronak, I want to see the code that you are using to add a node,update a node and delete a node.Put these codes in your question itself, I suspect you have not got the difference between adding a node and updating a node and you don't have to call me sir :)

Comment: In this case a new node will be added even if you are just updating your data.Hence your `onChildAdded` is getting called all the time.